# Eclipse CDT: illegal virtual folder names?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have created a CDT managed-build project with a list of virtual folders. Certain folder icons are "barred", which apparently means the enclosed files are excluded from the build (see Stand-alone Debugger User Guide > References > C/C++ Views and Editors). A sample is attached: [Sample of barred virtual folder icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As2Kt.png)

I was able to circumvent the problem by renaming the virtual folders. In fact, I found that the name I wanted, preceded by an underscore, usually seemed to work. But the behavior is very capricious, and sometimes I managed to game the system by using a name starting with a double underscore and then deleting the first one.

Does anyone know what is happening to me? Thanks in avance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what was happening. I was converting a project that had already been compiled to use Virtual Folders, so I think the output folder (e.g. ${ProjDirPath}/Debug) already had subfolders with the names I was trying to create.